# Why can't I use json.dump and json.loads back to back?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Why does this code produce a string (where `txt_file.txt` contains a dictionary placed there with `json.dump()`):

```
import json

f = open("txt_file.txt", "r+")
print(json.loads(f.read()))
```

But this produces an error:

```
import json

f = open("txt_file.txt", "r+")

dict = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
}

json.dump(dict, f) 

print(json.loads(f.read()))
```

I get an error thrown by the last line:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

When I check the `txt_file.txt`, it is updated, so there was no issue with the `json.dump()`.

Comment: Because you are reading from the end of the file.

Comment: You could do `f.seek(0)` or reopen the file.

Comment: Also, there's little reason not to use `json.load(f)`, as `load` is [literally](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/json/__init__.py#L274) just a wrapper around calling `loads` on the result of `f.read()` anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this, properly opening and closing the files:

```
import json

data = {   # `dict` is a bad name
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
}

with open("txt_file.txt", 'w') as fout :
    json.dump(data, fout) 

with open("txt_file.txt") as fin :
    print(json.loads(fin.read()))
```